# How to do dot density in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, density

I have some census tract polygons with language spoken at home attribute data behind them. I created them in ArcMap and produced a dot density map. However, after importing to AGOL it's only the polygons. I am aiming to create a swipe map comparing two maps visualizing the growth of language outwards from the city to suburbs over 20 years.

Here's a before and after image of the tracts in ArcMap, then AGOL:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API using the [Dot Density Renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/dotdensityrenderer-amd.html):

> The DotDensityRenderer provides the ability to create dot density
>   visualizations on data. A dot density map can be used to visualize the
>   variation in spatial density of a discrete spatial phenomenon.

There is a sample available [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/renderer_dot_density.html).

(I'm not sure whether it's possible out-of-the-box in ArcGIS Online, so you may need to build something yourself using the JS API.)